# Can't access *.tmp file from Visual Basic 6 & Data Dynamics Active Reports

Tags: vb6, development-environment, activereports

Just started working on a legacy application for a new client in Visual Basic 6 (I know...yuck right...but money is money).  Every time I run the application, close it out, and return to Visual Basic I am unable to save the Data Dynamics Active Report. This is true even if I don't change the report (i.e. I hit save and I still get the error).

The error I am receiving is [image]

The name of the "tmp" file is different every time.

When this occurs (i.e. every time I run) I have to close Visual Basic and restart it.  This is killing my productivity.

Things I have already looked at/tried:

- I checked that the file does exist (it does)
- I've checked that I have access to the file (I do.  I am administrator and I temporarily gave the "Everyone" user "Full Control" of all the folders in the path.
- I've started visual basic 6 as an administrator (OS is windows 7 BTW)
- I've set compatibility mode for Visual Basic 6 to "Windows XP Service Pack 1" & pack 2 and just XP.
- I've done the same "Everyone" permissions for the directory that holds the visual basic project group file (there are a lot of *.tmp files that get created in that directory)

If I don't open the Data Dynamics Active Reports designer, I don't believe I get this error and I can save and rerun as needed.

I've looked on the internet ad nauseum for a solution but haven't found anything or even a mention of the same issue.

Thoughts?  I can't handle having to restart the entire development environment every time I make a change to the application.

Answer (score 1):

These files are normally generated by the compiler, and will many will come and go.

The issue is Windows 7 with UAC on - to be honest, I'm surprised you got the IDE started at all on Windows 7.

- You have to turn off UAC completely. Visual Studio 6 will not work with UAC on.
- Install Visual Studio 6 to a directory other than *c:\Program
  Files (x86)\*, e.g. *c:\vs6*). The Program Files directory has a lot of special-case permissions to it.

You may want to consider setting up a Windows XP Pro VM, as it is way, way easier to work with Visual Studio 6 in it.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I turned off UAC and installed into a different directory but to no avail.  If I can scrounge up a copy of XP somewhere, I will give that a go.  Thanks again.

Comment: i am running the vb6 ide without any problems on both my windows 7 machines (one 32 bit, the other 64 bit) .. you dont need to revert to windows xp ... i am not using the complete visual studio though, just the vb6 ide : Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 (SP6) For 32-bit Windows Development

Answer (score 0):

how do you run the application? do you use F5 or ctrl-F5?

do the tmp files remain there forever or do they disappear later? if they do, when do they disappear?

do you also get the error when you run the executable?